# IFTTT Applet for post linkedin share a link have a issue with image in linkedin post

Tags: metadata, linkedin-api, ifttt

I am using IFTTT webhook to Linkedin 'Link share' Applet to automate my social media posting journey.

I am facing an issue with image not fetching while posting on linkedin (https://www.linkedin.com/in/john-anora-979bb42aa)
Url and content are posted on Linkedin. Same Url works fine with Facebook and twitter posting via Applet.

Post have og:image tag for social media. Image follow rules which are mentioned/post with linkedin image post. [Here is my account link for sample single post]

Checked with https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/ which is working as expected.`